# Edit code sample to specify DES key value

Tags: java, security, encryption, key, des

I have a working code example that uses DES (see below), but I want to specify the key data to use. How can I edit the code sample to do this?

```
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;  
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;    
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;  
import javax.crypto.Cipher;  
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;  
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;  
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;  
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class DESEncryptionDecryption {

private static Cipher encryptCipher;  
private static Cipher decryptCipher; 
public static void main(String[] args) {  
try {
KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");  
SecretKey secretKey = keygenerator.generateKey();  

encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");  
encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);  
byte[] encryptedData = encryptData("Classified Information!");  

decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");  
decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);  
decryptData(encryptedData);
}}}
```

Comment: Why did you remove your `catch` clauses? Your code example doesn't compile.

Comment: used catch in my program in lappy.. just here did not paste that to reduce size of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use a `KeyGenerator`, use a `SecretKeyFactory`:

```
String desKey = "0123456789abcdef"; // value from user  
byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(desKey);

SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(keyBytes));
```

Note that DES is not a secure algorithm. Consider using AES or Triple DES (DESede).

---

For DESede:

```
String desKey = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"; // user value (24 bytes)  
byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(desKey);

SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(keyBytes));
```

---

For AES, just do:

```
String aesKey = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"; // user value (16/24/32 bytes)
byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(aesKey);
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
```

Comment: for AES or Triple DES (DESede), is i just have to replace DES With AES/DESede in this line? no other alteration needed? `SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");`

Comment: SecretKeyFactory working good as per your code. thanks for it.

Comment: @nitinkt To use DESede, change the call to `getInstance("DESede")` and also change the key spec (`DESedeKeySpec`). For AES, don't bother with a `SecretKeyFactory`, just do `SecretKey aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(byteValue, "AES");`.

Comment: What is the key length for DESede? as it is showing Exception `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key size`. And for AES, i am not able to understand what exactly to edit for AES. Can u elaborate more? Sorry to bother you, but i am working on a project where all three algorithms need to be implemented for user choice and i don't have any idea of these java classes.

Comment: @nitinkt See edits above. That should be enough to get you going. If you hit any errors, do some research and I'm sure you'll find many, many answers already.